# open an application during runtime in Mac OSX using netbeans

Tags: java, macos, netbeans, runtime, .app

I want to open an application during run time in Mac using netbeans i used the following code but it throws exception. I used this code for windows with few changes i used it in Mac. Can anyone pls suggest me the correct code.

```
else
  {
    try {

        Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();

        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/Applications/TextEdit.app /Users/apple/Documents/java files/scratch files/hi.rtf");


        A4 a4sObj = new A4(new String[]{jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().toString()});  


    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(serialportselection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } 


}
```

Comment: You could use `Desktop.edit` if you want to invoke the "default" editor for the file, see [How to Integrate with the Desktop Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/desktop.html) for more details

Comment: suppose if i want to open any other applications which is not default then this class will not be helpful for me

Comment: Mac Apps are just a special "folder", so you can't "run" them, instead you need to look in the `Contents/MacOS` directory (of the app bundle), which might be something more like `/Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit`. I would also recommend using `ProcessBuilder` over `Process` directly

Comment: ya i checked it in app bundle. But can you pls explain me the code as how shld i make my application run ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so that took a little bit of digging.  It seems the preferred way to run a `.app` bundle is to use the `open` command. In order to get the app to open a file, you have to use the `-a` parameter, for example...

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String cmd = "/Applications/TextEdit.app";
        //String cmd = "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app";
        String fileToEdit = "/Users/.../Documents/Test.txt";

        System.out.println("Cmd = " + cmd);
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("open", "-a", cmd, fileToEdit);
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        try {
            Process p = pb.start();
            Thread t = new Thread(new InputStreamConsumer(p.getInputStream()));
            t.start();
            int exitCode = p.waitFor();
            t.join();
            System.out.println("Exited with " + exitCode);
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static class InputStreamConsumer implements Runnable {

        private InputStream is;

        public InputStreamConsumer(InputStream is) {
            this.is = is;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            int read = -1;
            try {
                while ((read = is.read()) != -1) {
                    System.out.print((char)read);
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I used your code to open a file "hi.txt" but it prints the following  Cmd = /Application/TextEdit.app  The file /users/apple/Documents/hi.txt does not exist. Exited with 1

Comment: This is going to sound stupid, but try using `new File("/users/apple/Documents/hi.txt").exists()` and make sure the exists and is reachable by the current user.

Comment: The code above worked perfectly for me for both TextEdit and Sublime. Are you sure the file actually exists? Have you tried a different file?  Is the file readable by the current user?

Comment: hey sorry it works fine but there was a change in my file it was  .rtf  file which i was trying to open. Thanks a lot !!!!!!!

Comment: just another doubt. Can i use the same procedure for opening any application during runtime in Mac ?

Comment: In theory, yes. You may not need the `-a` parameter, but you should be able to test it (the original sources I adapted this from were opening the applications, without passing arguments to them, I got the `-a` parameter from the docs)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107019/discussion-between-sruthi-acg-and-madprogrammer).